# How to make html map show the url at bottom of browser?

Tags: html, dictionary, hyperlink

Normally when we hover over a link defined by `<a href="blah.com">this is a link</a>` we get a tool tip in the bottom corner of browser saying that its going to "blah.com".
Now I am trying to use `<map>`, which doesn't show a tool tip.

Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for. This is a slightly modified version of Jose Antonio's solution. Have added code to show tool-tip on bottom right of browser window.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmkFB/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

But if you want tool tips you are looking for the title attribute in the html tags.

If you are looking for the url in the browsers status bar I think It depends on the browser. (ex.: firefox 9 shows both the url for a and area tags)

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZxxN/)

Comment: He is looking for a tooltip like thing at the bottom right of the browser.

Comment: or bottom left ;)  The point is I want to let users know where the link goes to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned the `<map>` element supports the `title` attribute so you might want to do something like `<map title="your tool tip here" />`

Whether or not that gets rendered as tool tip will mostly depend on the user agent.

Here's a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/QhyU8/